# Re-enable keyboard shortcuts "first login" cheat-sheet

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys, login

How can you make the "first login" keyboard shortcuts pop-up re-appear at the next login (or make it re-appear at every login)?

I know you can pull up the cheat-sheet by pressing and holding the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

However, I am really looking for a configuration parameter (perhaps a value in dconf or in a hidden file in the home directory) that I can re-set to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the solution, and it is very simple!

Simply delete the file called `first_run.stamp` under the folders `.cache/unity` in your home directory.

```
rm ~/.cache/unity/first_run.stamp
```

Update: In Ubuntu 16.04, delete the file called `first_run.stamp` under the folders `.config/unity` in your home directory.

```
rm ~/.config/unity/first_run.stamp
```